# How to know how many of a particular kind of element exist in the current web page in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

There are many `<label name="delQ" style="cursor:pointer">Remove</label>`
elements in a web page; the elements are dynamically created. How to determine how many "delQ" exist in the current web page?

```
$('[name="delQ"]').live('click', function() {
//Get the number of name="delQ" in the current web page.
});
```

How to do it in Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('label[name="delQ"]').length;
```

[length](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/length)

> Returns the number of elements in the
>   jQuery object.

Comment: length is not a function. jQuery defines also .size() method that does the same.